# Tidy up and reduce JQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a Parallax Scrolling type website (hiding and unhiding multiple "slides" on a single html page)

I have the basic jQuery code set-up which works as it is:

```
var main = function() {
$('.to-the-articles').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = $('.active-slide').next();

    currentSlide.fadeOut(1200).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(1200).addClass('active-slide');
});

$('.nav-level1').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = $('.active-slide').next();

    currentSlide.fadeOut(0).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(1200).addClass('active-slide');
});

$('.nav-level2').click(function() {
    $('.active-slide').fadeOut(0).removeClass('active-slide');
    $('.level2').fadeIn(1200).addClass('active-slide');
});

$('.nav-level3').click(function() {
    $('.active-slide').fadeOut(0).removeClass('active-slide');
    $('.level3').fadeIn(1200).addClass('active-slide');
});

$('.nav-level4').click(function() {
    $('.active-slide').fadeOut(0).removeClass('active-slide');
    $('.level4').fadeIn(1200).addClass('active-slide');
});

$('.back-home').click(function() {
    $('.active-slide').fadeOut(0).removeClass('active-slide');
    $('.home').fadeIn(1200).addClass('active-slide');
});
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

As you can see I repeat the same action multiple times, just changing the target to make the active slide.

I have had a go at reducing the code:

```
var fade = function(target) {
    var nextSlide = $(target);
    $('.active-slide').fadeOut(0).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(1200).addClass('active-slide');
};

var main = function() {
    $('.to-the-articles').click(fade('.home'));

    $('.nav-level1').click(fade('.level1'));
    $('.nav-level2').click(fade('.level2'));
    $('.nav-level3').click(fade('.level3'));
    $('.nav-level4').click(fade('.level4'));

    $('.back-home').click(fade('.home'));
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Here I tried to create a function `fade` which is called when one of the selected classes are clicked, but instead it just runs the function`fade` as soon as the document is ready.

Could someone explain why function `fade` runs on `$(document).ready` and doesn't wait for the `.click()`?

Edit:

Here is the current working code, the first one above: http://jsfiddle.net/m924B/1/
(Note: don't know how to load the images, but if you click the smaller missing image it will take you to the landing page.)

Here is the second attempt at the code: http://jsfiddle.net/m924B/2/

Comment: Please provide the HTML, too. In fact, having a http://jsfiddle.net would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with your html looking something like this:

```
<div class="nav-level" data-level="1"></div>
<div class="nav-level" data-level="2"></div>
...
```

you can use the `HTML5` data attribute to build your `jQuery` selector strings:

```
$('.nav-level').click(function() {
    $('.active-slide').fadeOut(0).removeClass('active-slide');
    $('.level' + $(this).data("level")).fadeIn(1200).addClass('active-slide');
});
```

so you just use the class "nav-level" for all elements and differentiate between them by using  different values in the (custom) data-attribute "data-level".

Comment: Hey, added the code to JSFiddle, as you can see I'm trying to click `.nav-level` but direct the page to the slide `.level` instead. Would this code be able to do that?

Comment: fixed that for you: [fixed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m924B/3/).

you also had no `jQuery` included in your fiddle, plus you used the `.click()` function without anonymous callback function. i replaced it with the more recommendable `.on()` function.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the "why" question:

Because you *run* `fade` in the `click` handler assignment.

Putting `()` after a function reference *calls that function*.

Note the difference compared with the following:

```
$('.nav-level1').click(function() { fade('.level1'); });
```

This passes a function that doesn't run immediately–a reference to an anonymous function.

Calling the anonymous function on the click calls `fade`.

Further details:

- [Difference between calling function and referencing function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8227270/438992)
- [When do I use parenthesis and when do I not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7969111/438992)

Comment: Thanks for that Dave, really useful to understand!