# Attach event handler to function

Tags: javascript

In the following, I am assigning the click event to func(). When I load the page, the alert box shows up. Can someone explain why the event is being triggered? What exactly is happening behind the scenes? Do all events attached to a function get triggered when the DOM loads?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function initialize() {
            func.click += handler();
        }

        function handler(e) {
            alert('clicked');
        }

        function func() {

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because you're *calling* `handler` by coding `handler()`. The function *reference* is just `handler` without the parens that indicate a call, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/8227270/438992, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969088/when-do-i-use-parenthesis-and-when-do-i-not/7969111#7969111

Comment: [JavaScript Basics - MDN Learn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics)

Comment: "I am assigning the click event to func(). " really? review the code

Comment: Well now it's just silly because what's `func`?!

Comment: @Mark. Am I not assigning a click event on function func() ?

Comment: @user2383728: No, you are not.  You don't assign events to functions, that makes no sense.  You assign events to DOM elements.  These events trigger functions when you click on an element on the page.  Think about it... how can you *click* on a function? :-)

Comment: What he said.  Understanding these things are key to understanding of objects, properties and event handlers in JavaScript.  You are on your way to that AH HA moment!

Comment: I would make the suggestion to begin using addEventListener as you see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener  Its really clear what the intent is then

Comment: I understand that you attach events to dom elements, not functions. I was just curious to see if I had could get the same behavior for functions. Maybe, by dispatching a custom event. Silly me. Ya addEventListener is more clear as it would have given me a run time error (func.addEventListener() doesn't exist. Thanks a lot for your explanations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are *first-order* citizens.  Meaning, they act like variables.

`handler` is the "variable" holding your function.  `handler()` *calls* the function and returns a value - `undefined` in this case.

`func.click` is *not* an event, it's just a property.  You can attach properties to basically any variable/object in JavaScript.  It has no special meaning.  <strike>Also, `func.click` doesn't exist, so doing `+=` will probably give you an error since it's `undefined`.</strike>

Comment: Shouldn't be an error because of wacky JS type coercion, no? I think it'll just be the string "undefined" and... the function body that you're adding?

Comment: @DaveNewton: `func.click += handler();` is doing `func.click = func.click + handler();`, both of which are `undefined`.  EDIT: I tested it, and it turns out you get `NaN`!

Comment: NaN because `undefined + undefined` is NaN methinks

Comment: (The OP defined `func` and `handler`, I got a string back in the console, but that was Chrome and could have been console-related. In any case, not an error ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton: The original question had `func.click += handler();` (note the parenthesis).

Comment: Yes he is right. That was the issue. Its back to original now.

Comment: Oh right, forgot. I translated to reasonable code when I typed :/