# Confusion on function that return a function

Tags: javascript

Help me understand these following piece of codes. I'm still newbie in JavaScript.

We know that the following code will run alertbox **with A message**

```js
// 1
function box() {
  alert('A');
  return function() {
    alert('B');
  }
}
var x = box();
```

And we know that the following will run **alertbox A** then followed by **alertbox B**

```js
// 2
function box() {
  alert('A');
  return function() {
    alert('B');
  }
}
var x = box();
x();
```

**BUT** in code below the behavior is **just like** snippet no 1. I **expect** it to run **ONLY alertbox B.**

```js
// 3
function box() {
  alert('A');
  return function() {
    alert('B');
  }
}
var x = box; // no invoking box function
x();
```

**QUESTION**: Why did this happen to snippet 3? Didn't we only call x function? From snippet 1 and 2 we know that running x() will trigger alertbox B, but why didn't it appear on snippet 3?

Answer (score 3):

When you write `var x = box;` you're storing the function "BOX" on the variable X. You're not executing your box function. To execute, you need to use the parenthesis as `box()`.

Since you have just stored the function and did not run it, when you call `x()` will yield the same result as calling `box()`.

> **Simple example**

```
function print(value) {
  alert(value);
}
```

What happens when you call `print('xcode')`?
- Your browser will alert "XCODE" as you just called the function with that parameter.

Now:
`var x = print;`

Here I am copying the 'print' function over to 'x' variable.

Finally, what happens when you call `x('xcode again')`?
- Your browser will alert "XCODE AGAIN", just like before.

Comment: I understand this concept however the main issue is IF 'var x = box(); x()' is equal to run 'A' and 'B' why doesn't 'var x = box; x()' only run 'B' since we are not calling 'B' when declaring 'x' variable.

Comment: @xcode Because you've called `box` when you write `x()`. `x` is a *reference* to the `box` function. Calling `x` is calling `box` because they reference the same function.

Comment: You can think of a function as a value... You could do `var box = function() { alert('a') }`. You wouldn't have called it, just stored on `box` variable. Then you need to run it through `box()` afterwards to see the "A" on the screen

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are 95% of the way to understanding this, but you got derailed at the end.

You are correct that in the third snippet, we save the function to the variable `x`:

```
function box() {
  alert('A');
  return function() {
    alert('B');
  }
}
var x = box; // no invoking box function
x();
```

But because we did not actually invoke `box()`, we just store the function in the new variable, `var x`. So by calling `x()`, we are essentially just calling `box()`.

The only time that we would get the `alert('B')` is when the returned value of the `box` function is saved to a new variable, and then that new variable is called, exactly as we do in snippet 2.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
function box() {
  alert('A');
  return function() {
    alert('B');
  }
}

//fires box() thus firing alert('A');
//returns a function that holds alert('B');
var x = box();
```

.

```
function box() {
  alert('A');
  return function() {
    alert('B');
  }
}

//fires box() thus firing alert('A');
//returns a function that holds alert('B');
var x = box();

//fires the returned function alert('B');
x();
```

.

```
function box() {
  alert('A');
  return function() {
    alert('B');
  }
}

//sets x EQUAL to box, nothing special nothing happens
var x = box; // no invoking box function

//fires box() thus firing alert('A');
//returns a function that holds alert('B');
x();
```

Comment: So basically in #2 `var x = function() {return alert('B')}` while in #3 `var x = function() {alert('A'); return.........}` am i correct?

Comment: Bingo. The value of var x in #2 is literally what the return value of the function says: return function() { alert('B') }, while #3 you're just saying x IS box, and then firing x() which is the same as firing box(); You do nothing with the return like you did in #2, where you fired box then fired the return, so it's irrelevant and never fired.

Answer (score 0):

It alerts `A` because you *are* invoking `box`.

`x` is a reference to the function `box`. When you write `x()` it's the same as calling `box()`. It does *not* alert `B` because you didn't call the function *returned* by calling `box`.

```js
function box() {
  alert('A');
  return function() {
    alert('B');
  }
}
var x = box; // no invoking box function
x()();
```

This is the same as doing this:

```js
function box() {
  alert('A');
  return function() {
    alert('B');
  }
}

// x1 is a reference to the function box, which alerts, and returns a function
var x1 = box;

// x2 is now the return value of box, the function. A side effect is that
// "A" is alerted.
var x2 = x1();

// Now you're calling the function returned by `box`, which alerts "B".
x2(); // Alerts B
```

Comment: So youre implying that `var x = box; x()()` is the same as `var x = box(); x()`?

Comment: @xcode Same, but different: `x()()` runs both functions with no intermediate steps, while the latter allows you to "save up" the call to the method returned by `box` until you need it. This is called a function generator, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/8537635/438992, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7969111/438992, http://stackoverflow.com/a/8227270/438992.